# Why does pg_dump ignore .pgpass?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have created a .pgpass file which works perfectly for my psql command.

```
chris@ap2155489:~$ psql --host=my.example.com --port=12345 --username=chris -d example_db
psql (9.6.13)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: xxx, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

example_db=> \q
```

When I try to run pg_dump I get my password asked.

I did `chmod 0600` to my .pgpass file

```
chris@ap2155489:~$ pg_dump --host=my.example.com --port=12345 --username=chris -d example_db -f dbs/test.sql --clean
Password:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Both commands run from home directory

UPDATE:

```
~$ ll /usr/bin/pg_dump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 May  9  2019 /usr/bin/pg_dump -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper*
~$ ll /usr/bin/psql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 May  9  2019 /usr/bin/psql -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper*
```

Comment: That should work.  And does work for me.  Is pg_dump some kind of alias or wrapper?  What is the full path to each binary?

Comment: both `/usr/bin/`. I forgot to mention that I am not the admin and not one of the sudoers

Comment: Is /usr/bin/pg_dump a binary, or a shell script which then calls the real binary?

Comment: What happens when you `cat /usr/bin/pg_dump`?

Comment: @richyen it returns a perl script

Comment: @jjanes I updated my question, please take a look

Comment: Can you find the real pg_dump binary and use it directly? Something like `locate pg_dump` or `find /usr -name pg_dump` . The wrapper seems to be screwing something up.  Might want to ask whoever is in charge of your system about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like you're using an Ubuntu system that has `postgresql-client-common` installed.  `pg_dump` is overloaded by `pg_wrapper`, but `.pgpass` is supposed to work (I tried it on my test system and it's fine).  It seems that your sysadmin may have done something (possibly with Perl?) that has the side effect of making you unable to use `.pgpass` with `pg_dump`.

One possible way to know what's going on is by doing `perl -e "exec env"` and see what the `$HOME` var is set to (or maybe it got cleared out).  You can also possibly do an `strace pg_dump` and see which directories are touched -- this will generate a lot of output, so it might be hard for you to work with.

Ultimately, you will likely need to 1) talk with your sysadmin and see if the environment can be fixed up so that you can use `.pgpass` with the `pg_wrapper`'s pseudo-`pg_dump`, or 2) Use `pg_dump` directly (Usually, that would be located in `/usr/lib/postgresql/<version_number>/bin/pg_dump`, but you should probably locate it with `find /usr -name "pg_dump"`)